# Deadlocking /w ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

Summary: I'm trying to parallelize my system using ThreadPoolExecutor and I'm running into a deadlock issue. I know WHY I'm getting the issue, but I'm not very familiar with concurrency in context of java so I'm not sure what classes/methods to use:

Simple Example: My code parses a large xml-like tree, and then spawns a thread for the top level instruction. This thread runs; as it executes, it reads more of the xml tree and spawns more threads on the same ThreadPoolExecutor (I use 1 pool because there is a user-defined maximum). This happens until the xml tree is consumed.

When enough parent threads end up in the threadpool and all their child threads are still in the queue, they deadlock (because the parent threads are blocked on their children threads, who aren't running). Let's say my tree is

```
Parent thread
 Child Thread A
  Child Child Thread A1
  Child Child Thread A2
  Child Child Thread A3
 Child Thread B
 Child Thread C
```

I will now have the Parent thread, A, B, C, A1, A2, and A3 as threads. Let's assume my max threadpool is 2. This means that in the way it was parsed, P, A are in the thread pool and everything else is in the thread queue.

Here, every non leaf node will be blocked on the leaf nodes. Since the leaf nodes were parsed last, they aren't even in the threadpool (and instead in the queue). Thusly the leaf children never run, and the whole system is deadlocked.

Question: Is there some method call to kick the parent thread out of the running threadpool as soon as it creates child threads? I'm wary of using callbacks because my system can initiate concurrency optionally, so I don't really want to clutter code on the children classes to call back on a parent thread that may not even exist.

Also, how should I go about implementing some sort of thread queue picking algorithm (priority/clock/etc); is ThreadPoolExecutor the right class to be using?

Thanks.

Comment: After a thread pool finishes all it's work, it automatically returns to the thread pool.

What happens to *your* parent thread after it spawns more tasks? does it synchronously wait on them? 
If so, I can understand why the dead lock occurs. Otherwise, there should not be a problem.

Comment: That's exactly what happens. Is there something I can call to kick the parent thread off the threadpool?

Answer (score 2):

If you need something like "waiting threads" that wait for the child threads to finish until they can complete their work, have a look at [`java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). It allows you to spawn subtasks from parent tasks. While the parent tasks have to wait they do not block any threads.

The tasks themselves are implemented by subclassing [`java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html). You also find a code example in the JavaDoc there.

Maybe start with [Oracle's tutorial about Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)!

Comment: Excellent! I knew if I hung around this thread long enough somebody would come up with a solution I had never heard of. (This is not my question, I'm just an interested observer) :) From the description, this sounds promising. I'm off to read the tutorial. :) +1 for including a tutorial link and not just dry javadocs.

Comment: Thx. ForkJoinPool is a very elegant solution when dealing with recursive dependent subtasks. Btw.: The JavaDocs of RecursiveTask contain a simple example that's maybe easier to start with (and understand) than the one in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your initial question is, I think, "no" - if you're using a thread pool, you can't "yield" a thread back to the pool except by returning from the run() method.  Thread pools are restricted to a total number of threads, not a total number of "running" threads.

I'd recommend against having a thread in a pool block on other tasks in that same pool, for precisely the reason you're encountering.  If you need to do something along those lines, you probably want to either use separate ThreadPools (easier), or refactor your code so that, instead of the parent blocking on the child task, the child task invokes the parent upon completion via a callback.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a user defined maximum threadpool size; I only use 1 threadpool so I can manage that max count.

Comment: Then you're going to have to use something other than simple ThreadPool scheduling; Giovanni provided a link above that sounds promising, and you should be able to use the idea if you can't use the implementation for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an unbounded thread pool executor by calling `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`. This will in fact always allow the child to start running because a new thread **will** be created if needed. As Sbodd noticed, having the parent block on the child is not a great idea since you're unnecessarily tying up the resources of the parent thread, so I don't recommend this approach.

If your architecture is truly hierarchical and tree-shaped, using something like Akka might be a good fit for your problem, although there is a steep learning curve to them.

Alternatively, you can try using the [Google Guava listenable futures](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained). I have a [blog post](http://blog.giovannibotta.net/2013/11/fun-with-guavas-listeningexecutorservice.html) showing an example of a `ListeningExecutorService`, which allows you to register a callback on your tasks (callable/runnable) after they are done. I believe the Guava executors are far superior to the plain vanilla java ones and the ability to register callbacks allows solving problem like the one you describe in a very elegant way (reminiscent of a functional style of futures as used in Scala or other FPLs).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confused about what a thread pool does; a parent process that spawns child threads and then blocks, waiting for children to finish, **is still using up one of the threads in your pool**. I may be off base here, but the subtext of your question makes me think that you are thinking of thread pools like a 'quota' of simultaneously running threads, or like the number of available CPUs in a system; in other words, I suspect you believe that if an executor thread is blocked, it gets swapped out and another takes its place. If you believed that, then it makes sense that you wouldn't get why this deadlock happens.

From the *operating system's* point of view, this is true; something is always running if there are runnable threads. But from the thread pool's point of view, it's perfectly possible for N threads to be blocked, and the CPU goes on doing other people's work. When one of your parents spawns a child and then blocks, that freezes one of the N available pool threads; it doesn't just put it on the back-burner and work on something else the way the OS does. An unbounded thread pool would probably behave the way you want (provided you don't run out of memory, etc.) but you may want to reconsider your architecture into something that puts 'jobs' on a work queue and lets N threads work away at the jobs. You can use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` implementation with a custom comparator to make sure the right jobs get prioritized.

Comment: I totally get why this deadlock happens, and it's as you said. A more detailed example of my failure looks like:

Comment: Is there a possibility of unbounded recursion here (threads creating threads creating threads?) or is it a two-level stack? (i.e. command gets parsed, spawns a job, that jobs may spawns subtasks, but those subtasks never spawn sub-subtasks?) In that special case, you could have two executors (one for top-level tasks, one for second-level tasks) and that should never deadlock, because there's no opportunity for mutual dependencies...

Comment: A parent thread has 3 children (child a, b, c). Child thread a has 2 children (child a1, a2).

In this example, threads would be made for a, a1, a2, b, and c. I can't simply not make a thread for child a (even though it will eventually block on a1 and a2), since I don't know that child a is going to eventually make more threads.

Perhaps I am confused about what a threadpool can, which is why I am asking what type of java object I should be using to represent a more proper thread management system.

Comment: Threads can indeed create threads. I'm pretty much parsing a modified XML tree of any possible depth.

I've also got a user-defined maximum thread size, so that's why I only have 1 threadpool.

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to achieve behavior kind of like an OS running on real hardware: you want the ability to have more or less unbounded parent-child relationships, but somehow throttle things so that only N jobs run at once, analogous to a CPU with N cores? (Not sure how to do this yet, but it's an interesting question, and there may be some clever way to achieve a similar effect; if this is the case, I suggest maybe fleshing out the original question a bit more to describe this, and perhaps some sharper minds than I can help you come up with something… :)

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Ok, so we're narrowing in on the problem statement, and it is an interesting one, which helps. :) I have voted up your question to try to attract more attention - it would help if you update the original question (or upvote my previous comment to help make it more visible) so folks understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I apparently need more rep to upvote you, but I have updated the comment. Thank you for making it clear that my question was very confusing!

Comment: No problem; I edited it some as well to restate the problem a bit; I'm curious to read what people come up with. :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding threadpools correctly, but once the max threadpool size is reached, what happens when I try to submit a new task? I've been assuming the thread is still made and popped onto a queue, which waits until the active threads in the pool complete.

Comment: You are getting confused by `Thread` vs `Runnable`. A fixed-thread-pool executor creates N threads when created, and maintains a queue of `Runnable` objects. As those threads are available to do new work, they pull a Runnable off the queue and call its `run()` method. So you can't take a thread that is half-done executing run() and put it back in the queue; that thread is tied up until its run() method terminates (either by returning, or by throwing a `throwable`) Imagine each thread in the executor' pool in an infinite loop of {pull runnable off the queue; run it}(until executor is shut down)

Comment: @JVMATL Yes, you're right, that's exactly how it works. "Putting a thread back" only works when you use a ForkJoinPool.